# Can't show all nodes images in treeview in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, treeview, treenode

Creating a treeview, the images of nodes show them only when you click on the node... I'd like to disable this, and show images from all nodes without the needing of clicking on them. How to?

Comment: How did you attach the ImageList?

Comment: I simply create it, by the `dim` , and I make it equals

Comment: Could you show the code you're using?